# Как подсвечивать синтаксис webgl в Sublime Text Windows 10

Tags: javascript, sublime-text, webgl, glsl

Собственно не найду чем подсвечивать синтаксис GLSL, webgl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в webstorm это имеется, но и там надо именовать файлы `shader.glsl`